# flalign numbers way too far on the right

Tags: align

I am trying to center the numbers at the end but for some reason they are on the far right...

and on a side note: Is there any way I can get the text not cursive?

```
\subsection{123}

\begin{flalign}
&xxx:                                   &(\pm 0.1)\si{\second} \nonumber\\
\newline &yyy:                      &(\pm 0.005)\cdot{10^{-3}} \si{\meter} \nonumber\\
\newline &zzz:                &(\pm 0.001)\cdot{10^{-3}} \si{\meter} \nonumber
\end{flalign}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is one of the following two examples closer to the expected output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv0FT.png For both, I used a `tabular` instead of `flalign`.

Comment: They are both pretty much better than what I have right now. I am not really familiar with `tabular` and I get a bunch of errors when I tried it out... I guess I have to look into it a bit more, thanks for the advice though!

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchage.  When posting a question, it is best to include the minimum code required to illustrate your problem, that is code that will run.  In your case, one needs to include some packages.

Comment: Are you labeling the equations with the `xxx` etc?  In that case, it might be better to use `\tag{xxx}` and drop the `\nonumber`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here's the code for the second image. I you want to horizontally center the values in the second column, as one can see in the first image, you can use `\begin{tabular}{lc}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{ll}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
xxx:& ($\pm$ 0.1)\si{\second} \\
yyy:& ($\pm$ 0.005)$\cdot$\SI{E-3}{\meter} \\
zzz:& ($\pm$ 0.001)$\cdot$\SI{E-3}{\meter}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.  I suggest that you use `flalign*` if you don't want any of the equations to be numbered.  Scientific notation looks better with the `\times` symbol.  There should be a small non-breaking space between a number and its unit, so I added a `\,`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% List of packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\subsection{123}

\begin{flalign*}
    &\text{xxx}    &    &(\pm 0.1)\\
    &\text{yyy}    &    &(\pm 0.005) \times 10^{-3}\,\si{\second}\\
    &\text{zzz}    &    &(\pm 0.001) \times 10^{-3}\,\si{\second}\\
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have full control on the spacing, it's better to ise `alignat*`, combined with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` (which loads `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nccmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\subsection{123}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&xxx: &\qquad & (\pm 0.1)\si{\second} \\
\newline &yyy: & & (\pm 0.005)\cdot{10^{-3}} \si{\meter}\\
\newline &zzz: & & (\pm 0.001)\cdot{10^{-3}} \si{\meter}
\end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]